# Asyncio recursion limits and max thread handling

Tags: python, recursion, python-asyncio

I'm very new to asyncio and would like to know if I am going to run into any recursion limits or threading limits **specifically related to asyncio** with the following function. My friend thought it looked weird to be doing recursion with asyncio so I'd like to get a second opinion. Not worried about maximum recursion depth exceptions typical in any recursive function, just in how it might interact with how the recursive elements are also spawning new coroutines as each loop is asynchronous.

```py
async def walk_elements(context: 'Context', element, key_path: list = None):
    if key_path is None:
        key_path = []

    if isinstance(element, str):
        if some_condition(key_path[-1]):
            await do_something_else(context, element, key_path)
        return

    if isinstance(element, list):
        await asyncio.gather(*[walk_elements(
            context, v, key_path + [i.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')]) 
            for i, v in enumerate(element)])

    if isinstance(element, dict):
        await asyncio.gather(*[walk_elements(
            context, v, key_path + [k]) for k, v in element.items()])
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The fact that you're using `asyncio.gather` means that the "recursive" calls to `walk_elements()` will be spawned as separate tasks. In other words, recursion will be broken right there, and the new task will be spawned directly from the event loop. You have the effect as if you eliminated recursion in favor of an explicitly allocated stack (except here the equivalent of stack is not explicit, it's maintained by the event loop, but it's still heap-allocated).

Comment: Awesome @user4815162342 - Thank you very much for your insight. Appreciate it.